# dc.js Row chart default view sorted and not reorder while onclick

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a situation where displaying two-row chart side by side. I need to achieve sorting both the graph with group highest value, this I can achieve through chart.order().
Scenario:-

```
1. The initial load of the chart with sorted values.
2. on Click of the chart, Don't need the sorting or reordering of the bar. 
Filter can apply the chart without reordering the bar position
```

Is there any solution available?

[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/caravinden/a7jdw5ds/)

Comment: Are you sure is the correct jsFiddle?

Comment: I had to make some changes just to make it work. [http://fiddle.jshell.net/davcs86/ameh3qbt/3/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/davcs86/ameh3qbt/3/)

Comment: @davcs86 sorry I have updated the jsFiddle :d http://fiddle.jshell.net/caravinden/a7jdw5ds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I think the simplest way to do this is just to take a snapshot of the values after the first render, and then use that for subsequent redraws.

We'll put this into a reusable function that creates an event handler for the `postRender` event:

```
function save_first_order() {
    var original_value = {}; // 1
    return function(chart) {
        chart.group().all().forEach(function(kv) { // 2
            original_value[kv.key] = kv.value;
        });
        chart.ordering(function(kv) { // 3
            return -original_value[kv.key];
        });
    };
}
```

The `postRender` event is fired only after the first time the chart is rendered (drawn). This function

1. keeps its own map of values in the closure: the map will only be affected by the chart it's applied to
2. when the render happens, it preserves all the values from the current 
   `group.all() in that map, and
3. changes the ordering function to use the values in the map instead of the current values

This assumes, of course, that no new values appear later on, but I think that's an implicit assumption in your question.

I put it inside a function so it can be reused, and applied it to both charts like so:

```
rowChart
  // ...
    .on('postRender', save_first_order());
```

(Note that the reusable function is called in order to create the closure, and it returns a function which is the actual event handler.)

[image: row chart not reordered]

Fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/04fcvgvu/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot... this is really appreciated. It's work like charm.:d